# gnutls_handshake error at crawling https pages

Tags: php, curl, gnutls

I want to crawl some https pages with php curl. PHP throws the following error:

> gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.

My php is self compiled with the following parameters: `--with-curl --with-openssl`. I've also set the curl parameters `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to 0.

The `phpinfo()` method displays me in the curl section the SSL-Version: GnuTLS/2.12.20

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: We need more details about the server and the fatal alert. Do you have the URL and alert number? Can you try with `openssl s_client` and TLS 1.0 (as opposed to SSLv3)? Also, just [bike shedding](http://bikeshed.com/), but this is probably bad idea: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `0`. It may work for a crawler with no real security or confidentiality requirements. But I would not make a habit of it :)

Comment: I doubt that it uses OpenSSL library since the error message clearly says it comes from GnuTLS. So it looks like your are not using the PHP you compiled. Apart from that receiving an alert can just mean anything, i.e. more details are needed to track down the problem (like the URL you are trying to access).